# I am dealing with a possible array in assembly, but I cannot figure out what the starter value is

Tags: c, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, disassembly

Size contains the number 86.

```
var_10= dword ptr -10h
var_C= dword ptr -0Ch
size= dword ptr  8
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
sub     esp, 28h
mov     eax, [ebp+size]
mov     [esp], eax      ; size
call    _malloc
mov     ds:x, eax
mov     [ebp+var_C], 0
jmp     short loc_804889E

loc_804889E:                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mov     eax, [ebp+size]
sub     eax, 1
cmp     eax, [ebp+var_C]
jg      short loc_8048887

loc_8048887:                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
mov     edx, ds:x
mov     eax, [ebp+var_C]
add     edx, eax
mov     eax, [ebp+var_C]
add     eax, 16h
mov     [edx], al
add     [ebp+var_C], 1
```

I am having difficulties reversing this portion of a project I am working on. There's a portion of the code where `ds:x` is moved into `edx` and is added with `var_c` and I am unsure where to go with that.

To me the program looks like it calls `malloc` and then moves that into `ds:x` and then moves `0` to `var_c`.

After that it simply subtracts `1` from the size of my pointer array and compares that number to `0`, then jumps to a portion where it adds `ds:x` into `edx` so it can add `eax` to `edx`.

Am I dealing with some sort of array here? What is the first value that's going to go into `edx` in `loc_8048887`? Another way this could help would be to see a C equivalent of it... But that would be what I am trying to accomplish and would rather learn the solution through a different means.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In x86 assembly there's no strict distinction between a variable stored in memory and an array in memory. It only depends on how you access the memory region. All you have is code and data. Anyway, I'd say that **`ds:x` is an array** as because of this code here:

```
mov     edx, ds:x        ; edx = [x]
mov     eax, [ebp+var_C] ; eax = something
add     edx, eax         ; edx = [x] + something
mov     eax, [ebp+var_C] ; eax = something
add     eax, 16h         ; eax = something + 0x16
mov     [edx], al        ; [[x] + something ] = al . Yes, ds:x is an array!
```

What is the value of `edx` in `loc_8048887`? To find it out you only need some very basic debugging skills. I assume you have `gdb` at hand, if not, get it ASAP. Then compile the code with debug symbols and link it, then run `gdb` with the executable, set a code breakpoint at `loc_8048887`, run the program with `r`, and finally check the value of `edx`.

These are the commands you need:

```
gdb myexecutable
(gdb) b loc_8048887
(gdb) r
(gdb) info registers edx
```

Comment: GDB Makes life so much easier! Thank you!