# What is the final output of eax for the final section (NOP) of the following x86 code snippet?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have no idea how to read this and tutorials seem like a lot of trouble for one question about assembler I might never touch again.

```
MOV $16457,%ebx
MOV $17458,%eax
MOV $7086,%ecx
CMP %eax,%ebx
JL L1
JMP L2
L1:
IMUL %eax,%ebx
ADD %eax,%ebx
MOV %ebx,%eax
SUB %ecx,%eax
JMP L3
L2:
IMUL %eax,%ebx
SUB %eax,%ebx
MOV %ebx,%eax
ADD %ecx,%eax
L3:
NOP
```

Comment: I suggest you to single-step this code in a debugger, eg. GDB. Or, if you only need the state of `eax` register in the end, just set a breakpoint at the last instruction (`nop`) or at `L3`, run the program and when you arrive at the breakpoint, check the value of `eax`. See my answer to another question for an example how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600780/i-am-dealing-with-a-possible-array-in-assembly-but-i-cannot-figure-out-what-the/20600996#20600996

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code at L1 calculates (16457*17458)+17458-7086 producing 287316678